# TypeScript type of HTML file input to be given to useRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to specify `input type='file'` as `ref` but I can't find the type part. Basically, I want to know the type of this part: `const upload = useRef<any>(null)`.

```
export default function ImgUpload() {
    const [imgFile, setImgFile] = useState<string[]>([]);
    const upload = useRef<any>(null);

    const imgUpload = () => {
        console.log(upload.current.files[0], upload.current.files[1]);
        setImgFile(prev => [...prev, URL.createObjectURL(upload.current.files[0])]);
    };

    return (
        <>
        <h1>image upload</h1>
        <input
            type='file'
            ref={upload}
            multiple
            onChange={imgUpload}
            accept='image/*'
            style={{
            zIndex: '2',
            marginBottom: '10px',
            cursor: 'pointer',
            }}
            />
        <h2>이미지 저장소</h2>
        <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
            {imgFile?.map((img, idx) => (
            <div key={idx} style={{ margin: '20px', border: '1px solid black' }}>
                <img
                style={{ width: '200px', height: '200px ' }}
                src={img}
                alt='img'
                />
            </div>
        ))}
        </div>
    </>
);
```

Comment: If this related to typescript try to use it like this:  React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow @kimjuno97! Your question wasn't clear so I edited it, assuming that I understood what you wanted to say (feel free to edit if it's not exactly what you wanted). Also, I posted an answer. Let me know in the comment section there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [HTMLInputElement](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L6916) as shown below. And you would need to console log and use it after a check as `files` is of type `files: FileList | null`.

```
const upload = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
```

```
const imgUpload = () => {
  if (!upload.current?.files) return;
  console.log(upload.current.files[0], upload.current.files[1]);
  setImgFile((prev) => [...prev, URL.createObjectURL(upload.current.files[0])]);
};
```

Comment: wow..  I should have thought about it when you weren't there, but I didn't. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad I could help and it's okay, we all miss little things from time to time :)